# for (x in y) VS for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) Where x is an array of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Where `y` is an array of objects,

```
y = [
    {property:"",property2:""},
    {property:"",property2:""},
    {property:"",property2:""},
    {property:"",property2:""},
    {property:"",property2:""}
]
```

could someone please tell me why,

```
for (x in y) {
    console.log(x[y].property);
}
```

is so many times slower than,

```
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[y].property);
}
```

Comment: the equivalent in your first example would be `for( x of y ) {  ... }` and not `in`.

Comment: If x is an array, it should be `for (y in x) {`...

Comment: what is your environment ? browser (which one and which version?) or other (node.js ? ...). Which OS ? The language in itself doesn't have performance, implementations (JavaScript engines) have.

Answer (score 4):

In the following [benchmark](http://nodesimplified.com/performance-check-on-different-types-of-for-loop-available-in-the-javascript/); you i'll see that in chrome version `62.0.3202`, `for...in...` is faster.

The speed of one or another looping style is depending on the `javascript engine` running it.

So if you want to know which one is faster and why you should start to look at the `node.js` version you are using; and then look for explaination about how the specific engine is made.

[image]

---

In [this](https://www.nearform.com/blog/node-js-is-getting-a-new-v8-with-turbofan/) other benchmark about `node.js` from `v5.x` to `v6.x`.

You see how much the speed has changed

[image]

So if in `v5.1.281.102` it was way more optimized to use a `for-in`, in `v6.1.361` it's better to use `Object.keys` associated to a `for` loop.